# Canadian Postal Code Boundaries from Google Maps

Tags: r, coordinates, google-maps, mapping

I am working with the R and Python languages.

Suppose I search for the following Canadian Postal Code (M5V 3L9) on Google Maps:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Toronto,+ON+M5V+3L9/@43.642566,-79.3875851,18z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x882b34d436f9c825:0x9e9c6195e38030f2!8m2!3d43.6429129!4d-79.3853443!16s%2Fg%2F1tvq4rqd?entry=ttu

When I search for this, I can see that the "perimeter" of this Postal Code is highlighted in red:

[image]

**My Question:**  (Using Selenium via R/Python) From an HTML/CSS/XML perspective - I am trying to get a list of all coordinates that make up the boundary of this perimeter.

I have been trying to explore the source code that is generated from this website to try and see if there is something I can do to see where the source code of this perimeter (e.g. in JSON) is being stored - but so far, I can't find anything:

[image]

I was hoping that perhaps there might be something which would allow me to use Selenium to repeatedly click around this perimeter and extract the longitude/latitude points - but so far, I can not find anything.

Can someone please show me how to do this?

Thanks!

**Note**: Generic Selenium Code:

```
library(RSelenium)
library(wdman)
library(netstat)

selenium()
seleium_object <- selenium(retcommand = T, check = F)

remote_driver <- rsDriver(browser = "chrome", chromever = "114.0.5735.90", verbose = F, port = free_port())

remDr<- remote_driver$client


remDr$navigate("https://www.google.com/maps/place/Toronto,+ON+M5V+3L9/@43.642566,-79.3875851,18z/data=!4m6!3m5!1s0x882b34d436f9c825:0x9e9c6195e38030f2!8m2!3d43.6429129!4d-79.3853443!16s%2Fg%2F1tvq4rqd?entry=ttu")
```

Comment: Scraping data out of google maps like this is often against the terms and conditions of use. If you are only interested in the boundaries, and not what google thinks the boundaries are (eg to compare with what someone else thinks the boundaries are) you should probably get them from somewhere else.

Comment: Try using openstreetmaps.org instead. It's possible Google draws those lines "behind the scenes" and then presents them to you as a single image (in fact, I'm pretty sure that's what it does), so it never sends you the data. If you absolutely insist on using Google Maps, save as high res image and georeference later